# Angular Router Activation Events

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I want to listen to Angular router events but only the first time they are activated.

So given the following scenario: `A > B`.  If I were to listen to `ActivationEnd` event, both A and B would be fired (as expected).

Now if I were to navigate to a subroute within say `A > B > C`, now `A` `B` and `C` `ActivationEnd` will fire again. I would only expect `C` to fire this time.

This is how the router works under the hood with route resolvers, I want to essentially do that behavior. My code looks like this:

```
this.router.events.pipe(
  tap((event) => console.log(event)),
  filter(event => event instanceof ActivationEnd)
).subscribe((event: ActivationEnd) => { ... })
```

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/router#router-events

Comment: @R.Richards how does that answer my question?

Comment: It doesn't, it was just a link to information on actual routing events. `ActivationEnd` didn't seem like a valid event, and I thought you could use that information to see what events to look for. Maybe you could use an rxjs switchMap with them, or something like that. I'll delete the comment if you feel it has no value.